# DMN VSCode extension model selection problem

Tags: visual-studio-code, kie, dmn

i am using the "KIE DMN Editor" extension (as part of the Kogito Bundle) in VSCode  to evaluate some (spring boot kogito) dmn examples projects (traffic violation). I am also trying to modify the project by adding some models and test scenarios. However whenever i try to select an existing dmn file (for a test scenario or for inclusion in an other model), non of them is enlisted, so i cannot select them (although there are some .dmn files in my resources library.) Please see screenshot.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXcQT.png)

Does anyone has an idea what do i miss?
Thank you for any help! :)

Regards,
Alex

I am trying to select my models for inclusion or testing.

Comment: The problem was due to collision with other vscode extensions or due to the multiproject workspace i was using. I don't know. Switching to a dedicated vscode instance with the required plugins installed only resolved the problem.